# if this is my json object - how do I access the object in my handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, httphandler

```
  var handler = "HttpHandlers/UpdateAdditionalCoverageDetailsHandler.ashx";
                var coverages = { PersonID: personId, DetCode: "", Reimbursement: "", Deductible: "", MaximumPerAnnum: "", MaximumPerVisit: "", MaximumPerVisits: "", SvcCode: "" };
                var maximums = { PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: "" };
                var obj = { Coverages: coverages, CoverageCombinedMaximums: maximums };

                var objJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
                var data = '{ "items":' + objJson + '}';

                callHandler(handler, data, saveSuccessful, failure);
```

and my function to call the handler:

```
 function callHandler(handler, obj, onSuccess, onFail) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: handler,
                    data: obj, // obj,
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: onSuccess,
                    fail: onFail

                });

            }
```

and the method in my handler:

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        bool isSuccessful = true;

        var items = context.Request.Params["items"];

        if (isSuccessful)
        {

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string,object> dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(items);

        }
        else
        {
            SendErrorMessage(context);
            return;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're asking here?

Comment: var items in my handler is null....I do see something in there though...I will post.

Comment: This question evolved to the answer found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890557/how-to-properly-use-javascript-deserialization-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-com