# How to properly use javascript deserialization to convert a json string to a complex object?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, ashx

I have the following json object that is available in my .ashx handler (var items=):

```
{"Coverages":{"PersonID":10,"DetCode":"","Reimbursement":"","Deductible":"","MaximumPerAnnum":"","MaximumPerVisit":"","MaximumPerVisits":"","SvcCode":""},"CoverageCombinedMaximums":{"PersonID":10,"DetCode":["AAAAA","BBBBB","CCCCC"],"MaximumPerAnnum":""}} 

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        bool isSuccessful = true;

        var items = context.Request.Params["items"];
        if (isSuccessful)
        {

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            AdditionalCoveragesPackage package = ser.Deserialize<AdditionalCoveragesPackage>(items);


        }
        else
        {
            SendErrorMessage(context);
            return;
        } 
    }
```

Here is the structure of the class I'm trying to deserialize:

```
public class AdditionalCoverage
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string DetCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? Reimbursement { get; set; }
    public decimal? Deductible { get; set; }
    public decimal? MaximumPerAnnum { get; set; }
    public decimal? MaximumPerVisit { get; set; }
    public int? MaximumPerVisits { get; set; }
    public string SvcCode { get; set; }

    public AdditionalCoverage()
    {
    }
}

public class AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string SvcCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? MaximumPerAnnum { get; set; }
    public List<string> DetCode { get; set; }

    public AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum()
    {
    }
}

public class AdditionalCoveragesPackage
{
    public List<AdditionalCoverage> Coverages { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum> CoverageCombinedMaximums { get; set; }

    public AdditionalCoveragesPackage()
    {
    }

    public AdditionalCoveragesPackage(AdditionalCoverage coverage, AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum maximum)
    {
        List<AdditionalCoverage> coverages = new List<AdditionalCoverage>();
        coverages.Add(coverage);
        Coverages = coverages;

        List<AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum> maximums = new List<AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum>();
        maximums.Add(maximum);
        CoverageCombinedMaximums = maximums;
    }

    public AdditionalCoveragesPackage(List<AdditionalCoverage> coverages, List<AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum> maximums)
    {
        Coverages = coverages;
        CoverageCombinedMaximums = maximums;
    }
}
```

Edit: Here are my client side methods that need correction:

```
function saveCoverageDetails() {
                var handler = "HttpHandlers/UpdateAdditionalCoverageDetailsHandler.ashx";
                var coverages = { PersonID: personId, DetCode: "", Reimbursement: "", Deductible: "", MaximumPerAnnum: "", MaximumPerVisit: "", MaximumPerVisits: "", SvcCode: "" };
                var maximums = { PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: "" };
                var obj = { Coverages: coverages, CoverageCombinedMaximums: maximums };


                var data = ({ items: JSON.stringify(obj) });
                callHandler(handler, data, saveSuccessful, failure);

            }
   function callHandler(handler, obj, onSuccess, onFail) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: handler,
                    data: obj,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: onSuccess,
                    fail: onFail

                });

            }
```

When I'm using the javascript serializer it does return my AdditionalCoveragesPackage object - however - both of the properties: Coverages and CombinedMaximums are empty.  How to get this to properly deserialize my json string?

Comment: Why are you using a List if you're only passing one item?

Comment: I can pass multiples.  I'm testing it - i.e. list of one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON string `Coverages` and `CoverageCombinedMaximums` are simple objects, not arrays, so:

```
public class AdditionalCoveragesPackage
{
    public AdditionalCoverage Coverages { get; set; }
    public AdditionalCoverageCombinedMaximum CoverageCombinedMaximums { get; set; }
}
```

Also in your example JSON:

```
"MaximumPerAnnum":""
```

so make sure you define the corresponding property as a nullable decimal:

```
public decimal? MaximumPerAnnum { get; set; }
```

or the deserializer will blow.

Comment: thanks for catching the nullable decimal (voted up your answer).  The AdditionalCoveragesPackages can be a list<T> of both objects.  My client side construction of my object seems to be the issue.  I have posted that to see if you can spot what I'm missing syntatically.

Comment: Ends up the json string was busted cause I used strings instead of zeros for nullable decimals.  Fried chicken brain!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `Coverages` and `CombinedMaximums` properties in your JSON are objects, not arrays.
You should change those to arrays or change your C# class to not use `List<T>`s.

Comment: You have me on the right track (so I voted it up).   My client side construction of my object seems to be the issue.  I have posted that to see if you can spot what I'm missing syntatically.

Comment: You're missing an array (eg, `[ 1, 2, 3]`)

Comment: where?  This is where I'm lost.  When I change my client script (surround the coverages and maximums {} with [] - my items in the ashx returns null....

Comment: You want `var coverages = [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ]`

Comment: if I change coverages and maximums to:                 var coverages = [{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: "", Reimbursement: "", Deductible: "", MaximumPerAnnum: "", MaximumPerVisit: "", MaximumPerVisits: "", SvcCode: "" },{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: "", Reimbursement: "", Deductible: "", MaximumPerAnnum: "", MaximumPerVisit: "", MaximumPerVisits: "", SvcCode: "" }];
                var maximums = [{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: "" },{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: "" }]; items in my ashx is null..

Answer (score 0):

[SLAKS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) and [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) both helped a ton.  Ends up it works if I compose my JSON string as below (I had the array structured incorrectly and was passing empty strings instead of zeros for my numeric types).  Here's the corrected client code:

```
 var handler = "HttpHandlers/UpdateAdditionalCoverageDetailsHandler.ashx";
                var coverages = [{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: "", Reimbursement: 0, Deductible: 0, MaximumPerAnnum: 0, MaximumPerVisit: 0, MaximumPerVisits: 0, SvcCode: "" }, { PersonID: personId, DetCode: "CHIROP", Reimbursement: 0, Deductible: 0, MaximumPerAnnum: 0, MaximumPerVisit: 0, MaximumPerVisits: 0, SvcCode: ""}];
                var maximums = [{ PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: 0 }, { PersonID: personId, DetCode: ["ACUPUN", "PODIAT", "OSTEOP"], MaximumPerAnnum: 0}];
                var obj = { Coverages: coverages, CoverageCombinedMaximums: maximums };

                var data = ({ items: JSON.stringify(obj) });
                callHandler(handler, data, saveSuccessful, failure);
```